# unknown error after uninstalling couple of references

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I had couple  of references  that caused my app problems so I uninstalled them  and after that I tried to run my app again and I got this error

```
           Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
           Error        DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073CF6] 
           AppxManifest.xml(68,27): error 
           0x80070002: Cannot install or update package c610de96-c868-42fc-8979- 
           c81d165cf23b_m2mhzkw71ghyc because 
           the splash screen image [SplashScreen.png] cannot be located. Verify that the package 
           contains an image 
           that can be used as a splash screen for the application, and that the package manifest 
           points to the 
           correct location in the package where this splash screen image can be found. SimuPro
```

Comment: Derive from your error info, it looks the project missing splash screen picture, please check the project AppxManifest file - > Visual Assets- > Splahs Screen option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the splash screen image [SplashScreen.png] cannot be located. Verify that the package
> contains an image

Derive from your error info, it looks the project missing splash screen picture, please check the project AppxManifest file - > Visual Assets- > Splash Screen option, and give it available splash screen value